# nslookup change standard server permanently

Tags: windows, networking, dns, nslookup

I've configured bind 9 in my local network environment to make management of servers a bit easier. However, `nslookup` requires the manual option of `"server={x}"` in interactive mode, because the default DNS server is still apparently set to my multifunctional router.

Is there a way to change this permanently so I don't have to go the extra mile each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can adjust the settings in your router, using the router's administrative interface to set the DNS servers to direct traffic to the correct DNS servers (Bind9).

YOu can also adjust the default DNS server through administrative network settings, selecting the network and clicking "Properties" in the alternate context menu (right click) in Windows machines.